# Add a model with a foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using Django and I have two models:

```
class Source(models.Model):
  def __str__(self):
    return "Test"



class SecurityGroup(models.Model)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  source = models.ForeignKey(Source)
```

I want that when I add a new SecurityGroup, automatically will append a new Source with his ID, and this ID will the source camp in the SecurityGroup.

I've been looking and I found override the method save(), but I don't know how to do..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned you can override the save method of `SecurityGroup` and create a new `Source` object there:

```
class SecurityGroup(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.source is None:
            self.source = Source.objects.create()
        super(SecurityGroup, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This is a bad solution. In this case, Your code override `source` on every `save` call.

Answer (score 2):

Read about [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/signals/).

`post_save` version:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=SecurityGroup)
def add_source(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        source = Source()
        source.save()
        instance.source = source
        instance.save()
```

`pre_save` version:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=SecurityGroup)
def add_source(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.source is None:
        source = Source()
        source.save()
        instance.source = source
```